R Error in `quarto_render()`: NoFound ipynb file
I can't solve a rendering issue with quarto_render().
I am trying to generate reports dynamically, passing a dataframe as a parameter from a quarto manuscript to a quarto document. Although the html file is generated the code raises an error.
ERROR: NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2): readfile '/Users/XXX/Documents/CS/RWD/CMF_R/minimal_test/minimal.embed.ipynb'
Path: /Users/XXX/Documents/CS/RWD/CMF_R/minimal_test/minimal.embed.ipynb

The qmd generator file is the following:

library(quarto)
library(jsonlite)
data(mtcars)

template_file <- "minimal.qmd"
output_file <- "render_test.html"
quarto_render(input = template_file, 
              output_file = output_file, 
              execute_params = list(df = jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars)))


The minimal.qmd file which generate the HTML report is the following:
---
title: "minimal"
editor: visual
params:
  df: NULL
---

```{r}
library(jsonlite)
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(params$df)
hist(df$mpg)

The YAML file is the following
project:
  type: manuscript

manuscript:
  article: minimal_render.qmd
  
params:
  df: NULL

Any idea on what is going wrong here?
EDIT: the complete error code when I render is:
processing file: minimal_render.qmd
  |.........................................                    |  67% [render]


Quitting from lines 6-17 [render] (minimal_render.qmd)
Error in `quarto_render()`:
✖ Error running quarto cli.
Caused by error:
! System command 'quarto' failed
Backtrace:
 1. quarto::quarto_render(input = template_file, output_file = output_file, execute_params = list(df = jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars)))
 2. quarto:::quarto_run(args, echo = TRUE, quarto_bin = quarto_bin)
                                                                                                   
Execution halted

On the qmd notebook, the error is a bit different:
ERROR: NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2): readfile '/Users/XXX/Documents/CS/RWD/CMF_R/minimal_test/minimal.embed.ipynb'
Path: /Users/XXX/Documents/CS/RWD/CMF_R/minimal_test/minimal.embed.ipynb

Stack trace:
Path: /Users/XXX/Documents/CS/RWD/CMF_R/minimal_test/minimal.embed.ipynb
    at readTextFileSync (ext:deno_fs/30_fs.js:859:10)
    at Object.Deno.readTextFileSync (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:5047:25)
    at postProcessRestorePreservedHtml (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:28089:23)
    at Object.postprocess (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:28237:9)
    at file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:70726:49
    at withTimingAsync (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:19479:31)
    at Object.complete (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:70725:23)
    at Object.onPostProcess (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:95092:76)
    at renderFileInternal (file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto.js:78257:26)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:153:7)
Error in `quarto_render()`:
✖ Error running quarto cli.
Caused by error:
! System command 'quarto' failed
Backtrace:
 1. quarto::quarto_render(input = template_file, output_file = output_file, execute_params = list(df = jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars)))
 2. quarto:::quarto_run(args, echo = TRUE, quarto_bin = quarto_bin)


I'm don't get the error. Which code does this error produce?
